# Postgres giving error on update

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, thingworx

I am using Postgresql persistence provider with Thingworx. When I am trying to run a service for ConnectivityActivation I am getting the following error

```
Cause: Execute Update failed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
```

Position: 145

When I tried this on some other thingworx server then I wasn't getting this error.

I am thinking in the direction that this might be some issue with the permissions but I am not able to find the root cause for this issue.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct or there could be some issue with the postgresql database.

The query run is

```
insert into transactiondata
("transId","category","api","devId","timestamp","state","country")
values ('123','category','api','123456','','Active','India')
on CONFLICT ("transId")
DO UPDATE SET "state" = 'Disabled', "timestamp" = '' ,"category" = 'NA';
```

Comment: you probably use "upsert", not update. and 9.4 does not have `on conflict` directive for insert

Comment: Postgres 9.4 does not support `on conflict()` You need to upgrade to a more recent version

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable information.

Comment: Is there any alternative available for ON CONFLICT  for postgres 9.4.5 as we have constraint of our war compatibility with only postgres 9.4.5 , postgres 9.5 not supported yet.